# Mobile view gets broken if post title has a long, unbreakable block of text

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

If someone includes a long block of text that doesn't have any spaces for break points, the mobile view breaks the location of the voting button pretty well.

See the picture (sorry no freehand circles!).

[image]